# using html tag and elements in text box leads to error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to convert my html file to pdf in that process i took all html tags and elements into an asp textfield on button click its giving the above error

code is

```
code.aspx

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtHtmlCode"  CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Width="90%" Text="" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="150px"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="BtnCreatePdf" runat="server" Text="Create PDF" OnClick="BtnCreatePdf_Click" CssClass="mybutton" />

code.aspx.cs



protected void BtnCreatePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    htmlString = TxtHtmlCode.Text;
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString);
    doc.Save(Response, false, "Sample.pdf");  
    doc.Close();
}
```

i check with breakpoints even its not going to button click function.

please help me..

Comment: You should consider a file upload instead of this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use HTML editor like [opensource ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew-asp.net).

It'll basically encode and decode html elements when you post the page back to server.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
        </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>

        <asp:Button ID="BtnCreatePdf" runat="server" Text="Create PDF"
            OnClick="BtnCreatePdf_Click" CssClass="mybutton" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

***FYI:*** I personally do not like to use `validateRequest="false"`; it'll end up creating security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `web.config` you'll want to do:

```
<HttpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Your other option, is to also append to your page directive at the top of your .aspx and apply:

```
<@Page ... validateRequest="false" %>
```

Keep in mind, by adding to `web.config` it will affect your entire site, compared to the page directive.  However, by adding this to your application, you obviate some built in security that Microsoft utilizes in the Web-Forms Framework.

Comment: "alleviate" may not be the correct word. "obviate" might be more correct.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Good call.